# Using "that" or not

Tags: sentence-construction

Which one is correct? / Which one is more natural?

- Can you tell them I'm busy?
- Can you tell them *that* I'm busy?

Comment: See if [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/145893/can-that-be-omitted-here) answers your question.

Comment: There are 66 questions tagged  [optional-that], you're bound to find an answer to yours if you look at them.

Comment: @PaulTanenbaum and "None" Yes, I think I have to search better after this. Thanks